# How do I check if each of 3 variables are the empty string?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

I have 3 input fields with text. I want to use an if statement with logical operators to check if any of the input fields are blank, but I can't use or(||) for the 3 variables.

What is the right way to use logical operators?

```
let name = $("#name").val();
let email = $("#email).val();
let color = $("#color).val();

if(name == '' && ( email == '' || color == '') {
  console.log("please complete form");
 }
else {
//submit data
}
```

the code works as desired if I leave the name field blank, but because name is true the if statement accepts it. How can I make it so the if statement checks if any of the input fields are blank?

Comment: You might not need JS. Just make these fields `required` and that should do.

Comment: Also did you try: `if(name == '' || email == '' || color == '') `

Comment: Your code is "if name is blank and either email or color is blank". It is not if any of them is blank.

Comment: Why you say that you can't use the OR operator for the three variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `||` for each:

```
if(name === '' || email === '' || color === '') {
```

You don't need the `()` groupings because the order of operations doesn't matter - you just want to see if *any* of the tests succeed.

Note that strict equality comparison (`===`) is pretty much always preferable over abstract equality comparison (`==`).

Because `.val()` always returns a string, and you want to check against the empty string, you could just check whether the value is truthy or not, if you wanted:

```
if(!name || !email || !color) {
```

Comment: That's really helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is considered 'falsy' meaning it is interpreted as `false` when using logical operators. Using that knowledge combined with the `!` (not) operator, we can do this:

```
if(!name || !email || !color) {
  console.log("please complete form");
}
```

That condition, in plain English, means something like "if not name or not email or not color"

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error (forgot a parenthesis in the `if` statement).

```
let name = $("#name").val();
let email = $("#email).val();
let color = $("#color).val();

if(name == '' && ( email == '' || color == '')) {
  console.log("please complete form");
 }
else {
//submit data
}
```